# in ember, how to get a reference to a model in that controller for saving

Tags: ember.js

I'm evaluating Emberjs in the context of whether we could port some of our code to it but maintain the same api so my first day really looking at it.

I'm using the Tom Dale tutorial but WITHOUT ember-data. I think I have kinda figured out how to get data into the app (thx @kingping2k). I just need to get this to save / update.

I have a doneEditing action which gets called when I click on it as seen by console but how do I get a reference to the model. Looking at the controller docs (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html), I don't see a really obvious property like `model` or something. How would I tell the PostController to save the post that it is getting back in its route? Also, do people normally use jQuery promises to do something else after the save has completed here(I'm assuming yes)?

I've included the relevant code with the doneEditing action at the bottom where I'm looking for help:

thx for any help

```
Model:
Hex.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    body: null,
    isEnabled: null,
    createdAt: null,
    save: function(data){
      console.log("you want to save this item");
      $.post( "api/post", data, function( data ) {
         // something here
    });
    }
});

View:
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">
  {{#if isEditing}}
  {{partial 'post/edit'}}
  <button {{action 'doneEditing'}}>Done</button>
  {{else}}
  <button {{action 'edit'}}>Edit</button>
  {{/if}}

  <h1>{{id}}</h1>
  {{outlet}}
</script>

Route:
Hex.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        console.log('called with: ' + params.post_id);
       return Hex.Post.findById(params.post_id);
    }
});


Controller:
Hex.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,

   actions:{
    edit: function() {
        this.set('isEditing', true);
    },

    doneEditing: function() {
        this.set('isEditing', false);
        console.log("this gets called");
        //this.get('content').save();
        //this.save();
        //console.log("here: " + this.model.id);
        //this.model.save(); //doesn't work ???
        // this.post.save(); //doesn't work ???
        //this.get('store').commit(); // prob no
    }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you return a model from the model hook it's then passed to the `setupController` in the route.  The default implementation of `setupController` does this, `controller.set('model', model)`

```
setupController:function(controller, model){
    controller.set('model', model');
}
```

so to get the model within the context of the controller just get that property.

```
var model = this.get('model')
```

I would return the promise, then you can trigger something on save/failure etc

```
save: function(){
  console.log("you want to save this item");
  return Ember.$.post( "api/post", JSON.stringify(this));
}

doneEditing: function() {
    this.set('isEditing', false);
    var model = this.get('model');
    model.save().then(function(){alert('saved');},
                      function(){alert('failure');});
}
```

And generally you'll put save in the reopen

```
Hex.Post.reopen({
  save: function(){
    console.log("you want to save this item");
    return Ember.$.post( "api/post", JSON.stringify(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: thx @kingping2k looks great and works well. You helped me so much today (on a Saturday no less). Great job; I really appreciate! I still will have more questions though

Comment: Keep em coming, I just had rotator cuff surgery a few days ago, so i'm stuck inside watching tv and programming 1 handed, it's keeping me sane.

Comment: sorry to hear about rotator cuff @kingpin2k ; hope you feel better soon - now if I can just get websockets going with this....